# Находим нужный класс с вложенным внутри button, кликаем, но вместо клика вносится какой-то текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Находим нужный класс с вложенным внутри button, кликаем, но вместо клика вносится какой-то текст

```
var prof = $('div.prof').length;
if(prof == true){
      $('div.prof > button.btn-success').click();  
}
```

*Консоль выбрасывает мне вот это сообщение*

**n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "div.prof > button.btn-success"]**

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести проблему вашего кода: http://jsfiddle.net/gjfkL4ba/2/ Видимо, нужно больше информации и больше кода. Возможно вывод в консоль этого текста и является результатом клика на ту кнопку.

Comment: https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse  просто допустим если скрипт находит класс .featured-item мне нужно нажать кнопку с классом btn-succes купить, но кнопка купить не нажимается а просто пишется лог в консоль

Comment: плюс к тому если я убираю div.prof >  то клики происходят, но происходят слишком часто, но по кнопкам с нужным классом клика не происходит

Comment: Простите, но я не хочу разбираться с кодом целого сайта, тем более, что вы сами, вроде бы, не знаете как он устроен. Возможно кто-то ещё вам поможет.

Comment: окей, спасибо за поддержку =)